# files missing from src folder (Jboss/eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss

[image]In JBoss (Eclipse) I am having a problem with my src files showing up in the src folder in the package explorer. As you can see from the picture on the left there is nothing in the folder for test, and no java files under main, but webapp. For example though I went to where the files are stored and show you that there are infact tons of files inside of the test folder. Any idea how to get them to show back up in the Package explorer in eclipse?

edit: srry forgot pic

Comment: Is your build path set correctly?

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse, make sure the filter is not turned on to hide types of files you're looking for.  Under Package Explorer, click the small down arrow to the top right of your listed projects.  In that list, select Filters... then make sure you're not filtering out the files you're looking for.  Checked items are hidden from your view.

Otherwise, the picture you've said you posted, I can't see.  So I'm sort of guessing what the problem really is here.

EDIT: OK, I see the picture now.

Answer (score 0):

Java files are shown under src/main/java at the top of the package explorer.  If you right-click the project name, select Build Path -> Configure Build Path...  and select the Source tab, you can see which folders have been designated as containing java source files.

Files in those folders will have been filtered out from the main "plain" type folders.  Eclipse treats stuff marked in "source" folders differently.  Mainly, it will attempt to compile java files it finds there.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, It was just that I was in regular Java perspective instead of the JBoss perspective. Honest silly mistake. Thanks for the replies though!